# How to use a variable as a parameter for a method from another class?

Tags: c#

There is a variable declared inside of a public partial class that I need to get as a parameter for a method that belongs to a class in another class.

This method receives two vectors/lists as parameters, and each one is in a different class, in different namespaces.

The main issue is with the one in the partial class. I tried to declare it as public, I also tried declaring it as private and then do the getter, I tried to call the method inside the private class and the other vector appears out of context. Long story short, nothing worked.

Do you have any solutions or can think of anything that can help?

Here is a code example

```
namespace x
{
    public class y
    {
        public List<object> hello; 
    }

    public partial class z
    {
        method(hello); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an **instance** of the class containing the `hello`-member. So without an instance of `y` there´s no `hello`. It makes no difference if that member is `public` or `private` as long as there´s no instance to which that member belongs.

```
var x = new MyClass();
```

Now you can use that instances members:

```
var z = new AnotherClass();
z.method(x.hello);
```

I´ve replaced your class-names to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The question you have to ask yourself is *which `y.hello`*? You can create multiple instances of your `y` class, so you can have multiple instances of `hello` too. So which one do you want?

- A new instance? Then create an instance and pass it in:

  ```
  y yInstance = new y();
  zInstance.method(yInstance.hello);
  ```
- An existing instance? The use that one:

  ```
  zInstance.method(someExistingY.hello);
  ```
- There is just one global `y`. No need for instances. Make the field `static` (This sounds as a bad design):

  ```
  public static List<object> hello;

  zInstance.method(y.hello);
  ```

Besides that there is other reason your code doesn't compile. You should always put method calls inside a method body, and never directly into the class. So you might need something like this, where `method` itself is defined in the other partial, since it isn't shown in your code sample here:

```
public partial class z
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        method(hello); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, If you add a description on his problems on the method declaration (check my answer) I would gladly delete mine in favor of this answer.